# Safe area constrained views get magnified with status bar toggled hidden/unhidden when navigating between UIViewControllers in iOS

Tags: ios, safearealayoutguide, ios-statusbar

Like the title says, there is an unexpected behavior that safe area constrained views *get magnified* on iOS when you try to navigate between UIViewControllers while toggling status bar hidden/unhidden.

A reproducible project can be found [here](https://github.com/inexcii/issue-statusbar-hidden-with-safearea).

I wonder if this is a bug in iOS.
Hope someone can explain why the issue happens and how can we fix it.

**Update**:

For "get magnified" part above:
The issue **only happens at a glance**, 2-3 times out of 5, during the UIViewController's navigation so you may have to pay much attention so as to notice it.
The magnified parts are: green background and two white boxes.
Note that the views keep the same size before-and-after the navigation.

Also, in the project, you might want to tap 'Button' and 'Close' button continuously so that it switches very quickly, to easily get issue noticed.

Comment: I run your code, I didn't find anything magnifying, neither two white box, nothing else. can you eloborate more?

Comment: hi, @ChatarVeerSuthar thank you for replying my question. I've updated the question(in the 'Update' part) for you so please refer it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Your code for hiding status bar & changing orientation causing flickering. Actually this works in background thread & you press Button and Close buttons so quickly that you feel it. OS is under transition which will effect your height of view.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [ .landscape ]
}
```

**Solution:**

1. Don't let user go back and forth so quickly until previous dismiss is not completed (completion handler)
2. Use Transition animation to lower the effect visually to end user.

Comment: Thank you for the replying. The demo is just a simplified version of this issue. Actually in our production app, we have much complicated view-combinations such as UINavigationController, some customized PageControl header in UICollectionView, all these combined parts result in that the flickering happens **every time** when we navigate to the sub-UIViewController. And the magnified effect gets stronger sometime when we change the UI or transition code.

Comment: Did you try to put code in DispatchQueue.main.async { //Your navigation code here }

Comment: No, I didn't. May I ask which part of code should I put into the main-thread block?

Comment: The navigation push and pop or present and dismiss, put in DispatchQueue.main.asyc { } block. than see what happens.

Comment: Give me some time, so I can work on your demo to get solution in code.